# Difference between > and >> while creating log file

Tags: shell

Whats the difference between these

```
  Python abcd.py > abcd.logs
```

and

```
Python abcd.py >> abcd.logs
```

In either case, the output of the program is stored in the file whose name is provided after the redirection operator.

Comment: This has nothing to do with python but with the terminal you are using.

Comment: Related: [What's is the difference between “>” and “>>” in shell command?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/382793/whats-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might depend on the shell you are using but the common behaviour is that `>` will overwrite the target file, while `>>` will append to it. If the target file does not exist it will be created in both cases.

Comment: How is it different for different shells?

Comment: @crafter It most likely isn't - I've never encountered any different behaviour as far as I can remember, but who knows, maybe there is some shell that behaves differently?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `>`:

- if the file exists: it will overwrite the file
- if the file doesn't exist: it will create the file

if you use `>>`:

- if the file exists: it will append to the file
- if the file doesn't exist: it will *create* the file

However you often can change this default behavior. And there's also `>|` which you can encounter in script files.

## Clobber - Option

The most common alteration to these rules are usually known as the "clobber"-option.

In bash you can achieve this with:

```
set -o noclobber # This will set the noclobber option
set +o noclobber # This will unset the noclobber option
```

In Zsh you can achieve this with:

```
setopt CLOBBER # This will set the CLOBBER option
unsetopt CLOBBER # This will unset the CLOBBER option
```

If the "clobber"-option is set (or the "noclobber"-option unset), it will work like the following:

If you use `>` with clobber-option:

- if the file exists: error
- if the file doesn't exist: it will create the file

if you use `>>` with clobber-option:

- if the file exists: it will append to the file
- if the file doesn't exist: error

if you use `>|` with clobber-option:

- if the file exists: it will overwrite the file
- if the file doesn't exist: it will create the file

Comment: In both the Windows command shell and bash (on debian) `>>` won't throw any error if the file does not exist, but behave as `>` and create a new file.

Comment: The `>>` operator will also create a file if it does not exist. I've never observed it throwing an error.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to mention `>|`, especially since you haven't explained anything about what it does. I wasn't aware that you could change the behaviour of `>` and `>>`, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: This is usually known as the `clobber` option. I will add it to my post.