# for loop writes only last result to file

Tags: bash, for-loop, increment

Hi there I've been playing a bit with for loops in BASH to edit a **FASTA** file.

The file has 24 headers that start with '>' character, as follow:

```
>CP068277.2
>CP068276.2
>CP068275.2
>CP068274.2
>CP068273.2
>CP068272.2
>CP068271.2
>CP068270.2
>CP068269.2
>CP068268.2
>CP068267.2
>CP068266.2
>CP068265.2
>CP068264.2
>CP068263.2
>CP068262.2
>CP068261.2
>CP068260.2
>CP068259.2
>CP068258.2
>CP068257.2
>CP068256.2
>CP068255.2
>CP086569.2
```

These are actually chromosomes and I need them to be in the form of `>chm1`, `>chm2`, etc.

I wrote the following for loop:

```
for ((c=1; c<=24; c++)); 
  do 
    sed 's/>/>chr'"$c"' /' CHM13v2.0_no-mito.fna > CHM13v2.0_no-mito_trial.fna;
done
```

The output is, however, showing only `>chm24` without accounting for the count operation (see below)..., anyone has any idea why?

```
>chr24 CP068277.2
>chr24 CP068276.2
>chr24 CP068275.2
>chr24 CP068274.2
>chr24 CP068273.2
>chr24 CP068272.2
>chr24 CP068271.2
>chr24 CP068270.2
>chr24 CP068269.2
>chr24 CP068268.2
>chr24 CP068267.2
>chr24 CP068266.2
>chr24 CP068265.2
>chr24 CP068264.2
>chr24 CP068263.2
>chr24 CP068262.2
>chr24 CP068261.2
>chr24 CP068260.2
>chr24 CP068259.2
>chr24 CP068258.2
>chr24 CP068257.2
>chr24 CP068256.2
>chr24 CP068255.2
>chr24 CP086569.2
```

P.S. no worries for the sequences following the `>chm24`, I have a way to remove them with `sed`; nonetheless, it would be nice to have everything done in one step

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: [Difference between > and >> while creating log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34649227/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is overwriting the output file on each iteration, the syntax for what you're trying to do would be:

```
for ((c=1; c<=24; c++)); 
  do 
    sed 's/>/>chr'"$c"' /' CHM13v2.0_no-mito.fna
done  > CHM13v2.0_no-mito_trial.fna
```

but this would be orders of magnitude more efficient and doesn't hard-code how many header lines you hope the file contains:

```
awk 'sub(/>/,""){$0=">chr" (++c) " " $0} 1' CHM13v2.0_no-mito.fna > CHM13v2.0_no-mito_trial.fna
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ed Morton, the solution with the for loop actually outputs 24 times each chromosome _e. g._ chr1 ... chr1, chr2 ... chr2, etc. However, awk is not only much faster but also produces the output I was looking for _e. g._ chr1 ... chr24. </br> It is just that I'm not really familiar with its use, thanks again!

Comment: @Matteo You're welcome. Right, I didn't say that for loop with sed was a good or correct approach, I was just giving you the syntax to get all of the output given what your code was doing. Glad the awk script worked out for you, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you'll have to do any more text processing as a shell loop is a bad starting point, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton, much appreciated! Do you know I was actually looking for a good book for coding using the shell; it is just that I'm a pure biologist and don't know much about these things, or any good book in particular... However, I will for sure get the one you recommended.

Comment: You could get "Shell Scripting Recipes" by Chris Johnson.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the loop, you store the output to CHM13v2.0_no-mito_trial.fna, overwriting the file. So, that file will only see the last iteration.

If you want all iterations, try replacing that line with:

```
sed 's/>/>chr'"$c"' /' CHM13v2.0_no-mito.fna >> CHM13v2.0_no-mito_trial.fna;
```

If you want each line to have $c placed on only that line. Try changing the sed edit to edit only that line, eg:

```
 sed ${c},${c}'s/>/>'"${c}"'/'
```

But, you will need to deal with not appending the unmatching lines to the output file.

Comment: You can use `>` if you put it after the `done` so it redirects the entire output of the loop. As a bonus, that's more efficient than opening the file for append over and over.